# android - Keep same action bar for all fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have developed an android application by extending to `FragmentActivity`. Everything works exactly as it done. I have put `NAVIGATION_MODES` as `TABS`. I have a `LISTVIEW` inside `TAB A` of `FRAGMENT A`. When the user clicks on `LISTVIEW ITEM`, new `Fragment/ACTIVITY` should launch showing the same `ACTION BAR` and same `TABS`. How can I achieve this.

Please suggest any methods.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the container of the current Fragment A with the ListView and replace the Fragment inside

so in the onclick method of the listview adapter:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(FragmentA.this.getParent().getID(), mNewFragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

since `FragmentA.this.getParent().getID()` is very clunky, search for the ID of the Container where FragmentA is located in, and use it instead. `R.id.FragmentAContainerID`

Comment: Thanks Yalla, it is working after I did what you told. Now one more issue. After launching of mNewFragment, when I click the back button, the previous fragmentactivity is not displayed instead the application is navigating to first opened screen. What should I do to show previous``FragmentActivity``. Below is my code.            ``mNewFragmentip = new mNewFragment();``
``FragmentTransaction ft = etFragmentManager().beginTransaction();``
``ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);``
``ft.replace(R.id.appmainpagenew, ip);``
``ft.addToBackStack("tag");``
``ft.commit();``

Comment: if you want to revert the fragmenttransition you have to call `ft.addToBackStack(null)` with null as tag, to add it to the default backstack. if you just want to switch between activities, and ignore this transition when pressing the back button just dont call ft.addToBackStack